cannot import punkt nltk
Due to security settings at work i cannot simply do nltk.download('punkt')
i therefore printed out the nltk.data.path and found where it's looking, then added the zip file into the location e.g it was looking at C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\envs\ml\nltk_data
so i added the punkt.zip file in nltk_data.
However when i run:
nltk.download('punkt', download_dir='C:\\Users\\name\Anaconda3\\envs\\ml\\nltk_data')

i get an error still
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [Errno 11001]
[nltk_data]     getaddrinfo failed>
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [Errno 

LookupError:
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:11001]

[nltk_data]     getaddrinfo failed>


nltk.download() should be run once, to fetch and install the requirement. The path you found is the destination, not the source.
This means that you have already simulated the effect of nltk.download; you should comment it out of your code and simply use the tokenizer. If this folder is indeed on nltk.data.path, everything will Just Work.
PS: In fact this is best practice in all environments: fetching resources with nltk.download() slows down your program and taxes the NLTK server unnecessarily. The download (on environments where it's possible) should take place in the install script, or in a test/error handler if the resource is not present. E.g.
try:
    nltk.sent_tokenize("just testing")
except LookupError:
    nltk.download("punkt")


Try with the command line approach.
python -m nltk.downloader punkt

or
python -m nltk.downloader -d C:\Users\name\Anaconda3\envs\ml\nltk_data punkt


Might be an SSL network issue, try this:
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download('punkt')

